# Angular 2 - two way binding for ngFor objects array with editable inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm new to Angular 2, trying to implement ngFor list of objects with editable inputs, be able to add a new object and save the data.
The data is:

```
business: { email: "email@something.com", 
locations: [
{ country: "US", city: "city 1", address_line_1: "address 1"},
{ country: "Australia", city: "city 1", address_line_1: "address 2"}
]}
```

In the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.businessForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]), 
        locationCountry: new FormControl(null)
});
addLocation() {
    this.isFormChanged = true;
    let newLocation = {};
    this.business.locations.push(newLocation);
}

removeLocation(item){
    if (null !== item) {
        this.isFormChanged = true;
        this.business.locations.splice(item, 1);
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="locations">Locations</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <button
                        id="locations"
                        class="btn btn-secondary"
                        type="button"
                        (click)="addLocation()">Add new address</button>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!--LOCATIONS LIST-->
            <ul class="locations-tag">
                <li *ngFor="let location of business?.locations; let index=index;">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger categories-tag-btn" (click)="removeLocation(index)">X</a>
                    <span>{{business?.locations[index].country}}</span>
                    <input
                            id="locations-{{index}}"
                            [(ngModel)]="business?.locations[index].country"
                            formControlName="locationCountry"
                            name="locations-{{index}}"
                            type="text" 
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Country" 
                            aria-label="Country"
                            value={{business?.locations[index].country}}>
                    ...

                </li>
            </ul>

    </div>
```

When it runs I get an error

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'US'. Current value: 'Australia'.
```

Looks like it changes all the inputs values to the last one.
I tried to implement the same idea through FormBuilder, but it didn't work out either.

Comment: Can you try to remove the ? after let location of business?.locations

Comment: I don't think reactive forms are good for two-way databinding, I think you'd want to try that with a template-driven form.

Comment: I just tried to remove ? - the same error plus one more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHhnad4oulLVZ3JHbCsP?p=preview). I remove formControlName because it's not FormsModule, it's ReactiveFormsModule - that is different.

For more information between [FormsModule(NgModel)](https://angular.io/guide/forms) vs [ReactiveFormsModule](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) read documentation. Also, it's better to delete **value** because you are using `[(ngModel)]` that is making two-way data-binding to the value.

```
  <input
                        id="locations-{{index}}"
                        [(ngModel)]="business?.locations[index].country"
                        name="locations-{{index}}"
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Country" 
                        aria-label="Country"
                        >
```

Comment: Thanks, @alexKhymenko! I will probably go on with ReactiveForms. The problem is there were more elements that worked with FormsModule and I hoped to solve it the same way.

Comment: @InnaZis Just remember to not use them both at the same time. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

(Answering since I am not yet allowed to comment). In addition to @alexKhymenko's answer, if you want to stick with ReactiveForms(Module), you will have to add the parent `formGroup`, `businessForm` you created in your component, also to the template. Not sure if this will fix your issue though, but try to add this attribute to the top `<div class="form-group">` like this `<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="businessForm">` of the template. If you are happy with non-reactive forms, then @alexKhymenko's answer might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, tried with this attribute, didn't help. I'll probably rewrite according to @alexKhymenko's suggestion.